# How to upload Multiple images to server in phonegap

Tags: cordova

I am developing iOs app using Phonegap, I want to upload multiple images to rails server at the same time using file uploading plugin, please anyone help with **how to upload multiple images to server**.

Answer (score 3):

I think If you need to upload multiple files, you couldn't upload all in same time. You need to make a loop to upload one file at a time.

For example:

```
//list of images URI
var items = [imgURI1,imgURI2,imgURI3];
$.each(items,function(){
    uploudPhoto($(this));
});
function uploadPhoto(imageURI) {
    var options = new FileUploadOptions();
    options.fileKey="file";
    options.fileName=imageURI.substr(imageURI.lastIndexOf('/')+1);
    options.mimeType="image/jpeg";

    var params = new Object();
    params.value1 = "test";
    params.value2 = "param";

    options.params = params;

    var ft = new FileTransfer();
    ft.upload(imageURI, encodeURI("http://some.server.com/upload.php"), win, fail, options);
}
```

Comment: If this answers your question, please mark as Answer for the other members (10x).